# How to set https proxy in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

> How to set https proxy in selenium and chromedriver? Here is my code
> to set up http proxy.

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
"C:\\Users\\lll\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        Proxy proxy=new Proxy();
        String proxyIpAndPort= "123.123.123.123:31288";
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyIpAndPort).setFtpProxy(proxyIpAndPort).setSslProxy(proxyIpAndPort);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.AVOIDING_PROXY, true);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ONLY_PROXYING_SELENIUM_TRAFFIC, true);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

but how can i set https proxy? i have tried:

> 1.String proxyIpAndport = "123.123.123.123:443", it is no internet.
>
> 2.String proxyIpAndPort = "123.123.123.123:443@HTTPS", it can't work of proxy.

Comment: Just like new HttpHost(ip, port, scheme(https));

Comment: just setting sslproxy is enough for https

Comment: it is to use for SSL connections.  The question is that i have a https proxy and how i can use it in selenium.

Comment: it already set in your code. just proxy.setSslProxy("proxyaddress:proxyport");